# How to add groups based on conditions in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large set of data where I need to calculate the sum of groups for specific columns in a table.  Here is an example of the table:

[image]

I need to sum up column H for each date group (column A) such that it will keep display this sum on the last row of the group.  In other words, on the first group that we can visibly see here for 3/21/13, we would sum up 38 + 2 + 21 and display 61 to the right of cell H4930.  This would be repeated throughout the data so as to display the sum of each group's H column entries at the lowest item in the group as aforenoted.

I am assuming that some VBA will be required here, but I am not sure how to attack this.  How would this be done?

Comment: I think you could easily do that with a Pivot Table, no programming required.

Comment: @iDevlop yes, the Pivot Table option is more clear for sure, but I have to use this particular format and so a non pivot table solution is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added 2 working columns before your Sum column.

Add: `=NOT(ISNA(MATCH(C2,$Q$2:$Q$3,0)))` to column N, where the Q2:Q3 are the numbers you wanted to check. Can be hidden.

Add: `=IF(N2,COUNTIFS(A3:$A$7416,A2,N3:$N$7416,TRUE)=0,"")` to column O. Can be hidden.

Add: `=IF(AND(N2,O2),SUMIFS(H2:$H$2,A2:$A$2,A2,N2:$N$2,TRUE),"")` to column P. This is your sum.

If you don't actually need to display all the data like this then a pivot table would be a lot clearer. You can filter based on numbers and so on easily.

edit: edited to check for specific codes in column C, per comment.
edit2: completely changed per comment. Requiring it to be inline with the last highlighted row is more complex.

Comment: Okay, that is fantastic.  I think that I need to modify this after contemplating it further with your input.  I am only needing the highlighted entry group sums and not all rows.  Is there a way to detect if something has been conditionally formatted or highlighted and then to only sum those groups?  The result that you give presently sums all "minutes" for an entire date range vs the highlighted ones in the dates.

Comment: @ylluminate the highlighted ones are highlighted based on what? column C always ending in "-4706"?

Comment: @ylluminate edited to check for the particular codes. Testing for a highlight is not possible through a built-in formula so would require VBA - checking the underlying conditions for the highlighting (the codes as you specify) is therefore preferable.

Comment: Okay, that is looking pretty good. Notwithstanding, I'm seeing a problem with the proper rows not being summed here.  I will go ahead and paste a sample for you here: http://cl.ly/0j3X2E0J0M1l  You will see that I simply highlighted the column you advised to create as red and ran it over the first 60 odd rows.  Those sums should obviously be in the yellow highlighted final entry for that date, so for example: http://cl.ly/image/1b2q1o302614

Comment: Ultimately I do have to display all of this data in this format and that is why your solution is the preferred option.  Really appreciate the additional edits.  The pivot table is interesting, and is more clear indeed, but not an option for this particular case.

Comment: I noticed one more thing that is needed and was curious if while you are fresh on this if you could add this tidbit. On the final column after P I would like to add that `minutes sum` to the Time column so as to give a "Time Ended" column for those particular dates.  I can make a new question if you like for this issue.  I'm on a time crunch and trying to hurry along so I apologize for the format.

Comment: @ylluminate, simply add the two together (so, your time ended column will be `time + minutes/60/24` or use the Time() function)

Comment: Okay, good deal.  I did try that initially and it didn't work properly returning a value error (`=B17+(P17/60/24)`).  I obviously quickly did something wrong so I'll play with that.

Comment: @ylluminate ah, i see the issue - the times in column B are actually text. You need to convert it to a number first. If you just need to get this out the door asap then do a quick find and replace on column B, replacing "P" with " P" and "A" with " A".

Comment: That is perfect, thanks! Is there an operation that I can use on the Q column in conjunction with =B17+TIME(0,P17,0) that would make facilitate if P is not nil, add this value to B? I was thinking about perhaps simply inserting a condition such as `if previous column > 0, add values` (ie: `=IF(P2>0,B2+TIME(0,P2,0))`).

Comment: Got it, I used ISNUMBER as in: `=IF(ISNUMBER(P2),B2+P2,"")`  Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes as suggested by Idevelop ..you can get this done using **pivot table**

**Select all the data -> goto Insert menu  ->Pivot table > say ok**

in Row field >**Place A column title**

in values field >**place H column title**

that's it

Let me know if you need more details.

Image :

[image]

Comment: Well, hitting a bit of a wall.  Perhaps it is the differential of Windows vs Mac, but it should be pretty much about the same.  For example, when I create a Pivot Table, I see the following: http://cl.ly/image/2M2n2Y0g121Z -- as you note I can drag columns around from "Field name" to the other fields below, but it's not lending itself easily to the result.  The goal is to have sums of only the highlighted items in the example above OR to at least have the sum for all of them as per the first Date column so as to be able to quickly look at only the highlighted rows w/ their accompanying sums.

Comment: Date(header) should be in Row labels :)

Comment: Very interesting, so as you see here: http://cl.ly/image/3U293n1Y0B01  The Dates are grouping properly, but the Sum of Time column is not actually calculating the sums of the times called per telephone number.  Further, is there a way to filter on multiple numbers?  So for example, if I only want rows that contain the endings of `-4706` and `-5173` in the number field?

Comment: Right click on pivot and do select sum as in the above image(refer image in my answer)

Comment: You'll need to also put Column C in the Row field (under Column A) then filter column C (in the pivot table) by the items you want to see.