# Writing an Excel macro to format a Table Bottom Line between different values

Tags: vba, excel, spreadsheet

I'm quite a newbie at Excel VBA (but I'm doing my best!) to try and solve this problem I have for my Excel spreadsheet work. I've trawled other questions but haven't found a solution I understand yet.

I'm trying to write a Macro that can insert a Table Bottom Line across the bottom of a the previous row when the values change, which you can see in this picture:

[image: Excel data example]

I would need the Table Bottom Line across the final **091** code, final **200** code, and so on. This would need to be automated.

If anyone has any solutions or ideas that can assist me, it would be a big help to me and my work!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA Excel - Inserting Subtotal Formulas into Specific Rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068103/vba-excel-inserting-subtotal-formulas-into-specific-rows)

Answer (score 0):

Hello this will help you

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
'Set the worksheet as a variable
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Tabelle1")
'check how many rows
x = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'check how many columns
y = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'loop through rows
For i = 2 To x
    'if value changes....
     If ws.Cells(i, 1) <> ws.Cells(i + 1, 1) Then
         '.... make a border at the bottom
         With ws.Range(ws.Cells(i, 1), ws.Cells(i, y)).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
             .LineStyle = xlContinuos
             .Weight = xlThin
         End With
     End If

Next i


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
Sub BottomLines()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim key As Variant

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For Each cell In Range("A1", cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its column A range form row 1 (header) down to its last not empty row
            .item(cell.Value) = cell.Row
        Next
        For Each key In .keys
            With cells(.item(key), 1).Resize(, 3).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @GoKura, did you get through it?